# Invalid character in header content ["Host"] Postman

Tags: testing, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, web-api-testing

When i try to test api with localhost:[port] it gives the invalid character in header ["Host"] console error. I am using dotnet core webApi. I cross checked the CORS configuration from api end it is fine. The issue is on the Postman side.
**Postman version**: v8.7.0

[image: I have attached the screenshot of the issue]

Comment: What's the error message, it will be above the request headers in the console.

Comment: @DannyDainton 'Invalid character in header content ["Host"]' is the error message

Comment: make sure that you don;t have custom host header added , remove that and use the automatic one that is shown in your screenshot

Comment: @PDHide i haven't added any thing in header.

Comment: I created the request again via Add Request menu and it works. I'm not sure if it is a problem with the update and old requests. The old one is still failing.

Comment: Just in case if it may help others getting this same error — I was using environment variables and the one that I was using for the URL had a new line character at the end. Removing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same error being reported for any forked or created Postman requests:

```
Error: Invalid character in header content ["Host"]
```

The request URL was using a global parameter:

```
{{BaseUri}}/some/sort/of/resource
```

In the console logs the following was reported (URLs redacted):

```
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9d14e81d-1e21-44a2-93ed-2758f0ad24fa
Host: my.url.co.uk↵
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

*Note the ↵ character at the end of the Host Header.*

The global *BaseUri* parameter did not appear to have a line break at the end of it. However, completely deleting said parameter and recreating it seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: The same happened, bro thanks solved it!

Comment: That's the culprit. However you don't need t o delete the parameter completely, just go to the environment screen and remove the newline char. see: https://snipboard.io/9lp8dP.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I also had same incident and I was able to find the error by exporting "My Workspace" content and open it from notepad++. Then change the encoding to "ANSI" from notepad++ (Encoding=> ANSI). You will notice special characters as below,

[image]

This can happen when you copy the url and paste in Postman and then try to edit it.

If you are getting this URL from someone what you can ask is to provide exported json file from postman. Then import it to your workspace.

Answer (score 3):

I thought the issue was in a variable I was using because the error was telling me there's an invalid character in my host `https://localhost:4431` which is exactly the value of my variable.

I figured out the invalid character was actually not in my variable but in the rest of the URL in my request.

Turns out, when copying endpoint names from the Swagger of my API, I was also copying an invisible character `%E2%80%8B`. I saw it when checking the API's console `RequestPath:/%E2%80%8BmyEndpoint`

Removing this invisible character solved the issue

Comment: Thank you for this. In my case, I do not see the invisible character. But this gave me an idea on what to do next :)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from question comments. by [Fidel Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4917016/fidel-garcia)

I created the request again via Add Request menu and it works. I'm not sure if it is a problem with the update and old requests. The old one is still failing.

===================================================

It also worked for me. I created new request with the same parameters and it worked.
I created a requested with and wrote the parameters in headers. After wrong requested I changed it to correct one (post request and parameters in body) and got the error. **After creating new request with correct configuration (post request parameters in body) it worked correctly.**

Comment: so what is the answer?

Comment: Creating NEW request with same (correct) configuration should solve the probelm.

Answer (score 1):

This has just happened to me to. All I did was to delete this " ↵ " characters at the places [shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5CNb.png).

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
I removed the authentication from Header then I re-enter the authentication credentials again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case enter after param and path generate error. Exact reason could be found in postman console.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because I added an extra blanckspace at the end of an environment variable deffinition. That extra space was being taken into account in the route when making a request.
Be careful with those extra blanck spaces.

Comment: Hi.  Consider move this answer into comments of the question.  Try to use answers just for solution.  It seems you want to help.  You can do the same post on comments.  This way you help all the community.  Thanks.